# What do you call your company's initiative to get feedback from end users?

Tags: user-research, research, user-engagement

IBM has its 'Sponsor User Program' and I've heard terms like 'Voice of the Customer' used before, but is there a standard term for this type of initiative?

I'm not asking how such a program works. I just need to know about terminology so I can do my own research.

Comment: I think this is very company culture dependend. What is it you want to research and how does the term help you with that? Maybe when you elaborate on that, someone might give insights you didn't think of.

Comment: I want to read about how successful companies run programs to engage with their users. Links would be fine. I just haven't had much luck searching because I don't know what terminology to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think the last company I worked in did this really well. added to their voice of customer (VOC), they also had 2 customer engagement programs where customers who signed up were sent

1. A monthly survey, this survey is used to gather desirability and perceived usefulness of features and improvements that the product team is considering building
2. Getting feedback on the specific features, app, website, and overall experience
3. Inviting them to participate in upcoming usability testing sessions.

for 3. another company i worked with called it 'customer day'

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific term for a company initiative of this sort.

In a general sense, I'd personally include this under the banner of User Research.

In terms of searching for examples of initiatives, you might want to think about terms such as:

- User engagement
- User satisfaction
- User feedback

Most of the efforts in this area typically focus on measuring or improving a particular metric (such as satisfaction). So perhaps search for things like "Examples of improving customer/user satisfaction" - If they display an improvement, the same article may well list the methodology they used.